# Asset file being loaded automatically in Rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a Rails application using Twitter Bootstrap. Everything is working fine. Now, I added a "custom.css" file to my "app/assests/stylesheets" folder. The file is blank. Still everything a good. Now I added a custom setting for the ".btn" class. Now when I refresh the webpage, the change is button is shown. I have not added the "custom.css" file in any of the project's HTML (or anywhere else).

So, my question is that why is the "custom.css" file being loaded automatically in my web app? Is it the default behaviour that whatever file I add to the "app/assets/stylesheets" folder, it wlll be automatically loaded?

Comment: you should read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your default application.css file, you'll have a line like this unless you removed it:

```
 *= require_tree .
```

This recursively includes all stylesheets under `app/assets/stylesheets`.

If you do not want this behaviour, remove that line, and include each stylesheet you do need explicitly with something like this:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require foo
 *= require bar
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Now I notice that there is similar line in "application.js" for JavaScripts.

Comment: But it seems that "*= require_tree ." part is commented. Am I wrong?

Comment: This: `/* ... */` is a CSS comment, correct. But the first comment block in `application.css` also serves as a manifest, with the special `*=` syntax for referencing other files to be compiled by the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right. In your application.css you have something like:

```
*= require_tree
```

This includes all files which are in your app/assets/stylesheets folder.